# Spring-Data-Neo4J: How Spring-Data-Neo4j manage Neo4J versions

Tags: java, spring, exception, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When i am using `Spring-Data-Neo4J` with `3.2.1.RELEASE` verison and `Neo4J` with `2.1.5`, my application run successfully. When i migrate my `Neo4J` to version `2.2.2` and `Spring-Data-Neo4J` to `3.2.2.RELEASE` i am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/impl/transaction/SpringTransactionManager
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.createTransactionManagerForOnePointEight(JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.java:110)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.createJtaTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.create(JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.<init>(JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean.java:35)
at com.harmeetsingh13.config.Neo4jConfig.neo4jTransactionManagerFactoryBean(Neo4jConfig.java:48)
at com.harmeetsingh13.config.Neo4jConfig.neo4jTransactionManager(Neo4jConfig.java:66)
at com.harmeetsingh13.config.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f77a14f4.CGLIB$neo4jTransactionManager$1(<generated>)
at com.harmeetsingh13.config.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f77a14f4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b430987b.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
at com.harmeetsingh13.config.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f77a14f4.neo4jTransactionManager(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1180)
... 97 more
```

This is because our `dependencies` version are not compatible. So, How `Spring-Data-Neo4J` manage versions of `Neo4J`?

Is it possible to use `Spring-Data-Neo4J 3.2.2.RELEASE` with `Neo4J 2.2.2`?

**UPDATE**

After @MichaelHunger suggestion, i am using following dependencies `Spring-Data-neo4J 3.4.0.M1` and `Neo4J 2.2.2`. So my following dependency graph is:

[image: Dependency Graph]

Comment: And what happened after you updated the versions? Can you pleas show the output of mvn dependency:tree not a screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 3.4.0.M1 or 3.3.1 (which is due this week) both of which provide compatibility with Neo4j 2.2.2

Comment: Hello @Michael version `3.3.1` is not exist in repository and `3.4.0.M1` is the `pre` version, i think this is not good for production. But i will test it.

Comment: Hey @MichaelHunger when i am using `Spring-Data-neo4J 3.4.0.M1` and `Neo4J 2.2.2`, i am getting following dependency error `Missing artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1`. But i have `neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1` dependency in my class path.

Comment: Can you check with mvn dependency:tree ?

Comment: Hey @MichaelHunger please check question, i was update my question with dependency graph.